# counting unique entry within a range that meet a specific criteria in another column in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Date    ref no. 
201307  abcd12345
201307  abcd12345
201307  abcd12345
201307  abcd12346
201307  abcd12347
201307  abcd12347
201307  abcd12348
201307  abcd12349
201308  abcd12310
201308  abcd12310
201308  abcd12310
201308  abcd12311
201308  abcd12312
201308  abcd12312

1) I would like to count the unique ref no. in column B but meet criteria in A.
example: in period 201307, the total no. of unique ref is = 5
in period 201308, the total no. of unique ref is = 3

Can you advise what is the formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image: tigervatar example for count unique by criteria]

The formula in cell E2 and copied down is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$15=D2)*($A$2:$A$15<>"")/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$15,$B$2:$B$15&""))
```

Comment: @user2715525, then you should probably mark this answer as accepted? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)